# Iterating through nested JSON where empty arrays might be present

Tags: jquery, json

I'm retrieving JSON by the `Get` method in jQuery and appending the data to an HTML table.

The JSON data is structured like this:

```
{
"response":{
     "message":"correct"
   },
 "products":[
             {
             "name":"tools",
             "productid":"14",
             "subproducts":[
                                  {
                                   "subproductname":"hammer",
                                   "subproductid":"24"
                                   },
                                    {
                                   "subproductname":"screw",
                                   "subproductid":"28"
                                   },
                            ],
               },
               {
             "name":"utilities",
             "productid":"15",
             "subproducts":[],
               },
            ]
    }
}
```

I can successfully parse the JSON to retrieve each instance of `name` and `productid` from the data and append to a new row in the table. However, i'm having trouble retrieving the `subproductname` from the data as the `subproducts` array does not always contain data (see above for a simple example).

**My jQuery code looks like this:**

```
$.getJSON('url' + name, function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.products.length; ++i) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td class='name'>" + data.response.products[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='id'>" + data.response.products[i].productid + "</td>");    
    tr.append("<td class='subproductid'>" + data.response.products[i].subproducts[0].subproductname + "</td>");
    $('#table').append(tr);
    };
 });
```

As it stands, I've added `[0]` to subproducts in the `tr.append` line which works to a small extent but my problem is that the data is only appended where the `subproducts` array also contains data. I'd like to be able to append all data where the `product` array is present regardless of whether the `subproducts` array contains any data. If there is data in the `subproducts` array it will be added into its td class but if not the text in the td class should remain blank and the `name` and `productid` data should still be appended.

I'm stumped as to how I'd overcome this - my thinking is I need to add another `for` line before I append the data to the table. Am I on the right lines here?

Comment: you don't need another for loop. since it looks there is only 1 subproduct by your usage `subproducts[0]` you need to check fot its existence/length

Comment: there is potentially more than one `subproduct`, but I only need to select one out of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the array contains anything with `length` before you try to access it :

```
$.getJSON('url' + name, function(data) {
    $.each( data.response.products, function(i, product) {
        var tr  = $('<tr />'),
            sub = product.subproducts.length ? product.subproducts[0].subproductname : '',
            td1 = $('<td />', {
                 'class' : 'name', 
                 text    : product.name
            }),
            td2 = $('<td />', {
                 'class' : 'id', 
                 text    : product.productid
            }),
            td3 = $('<td />', {
                 'class' : 'subproductid', 
                 text    : sub
            });

        tr.append(td1, td2, td3).appendTo('#table');
    });
});
```

if you need to, you can be more thorough, checking every step of the way.

```
var sub = '';

if ('subproducts' in product) { // that key exists

    if ( Array.isArray(procuct.subproducts) ) { // it's an array

        if ( procuct.subproducts.length ) { // it's not empty

            if ( 'subproductname' in procuct.subproducts[0] ) // and that key exists

                 sub = product.subproducts[0].subproductname;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is really verbose, and not the way you'd normally write something like this as you can join the checks in one single if statement, and you shouldn't really have to check every single thing, but you have to decide how uncertain you are that keys and objects will exist, and test for the things that could be missing etc. The above only shows you the different tests you can do.

Comment: This is really great. Used the first method and it's a neat way of structuring the complex JSON data i'm retrieving. Thanks!